# Hong Kong Disneyland Resort

Tags: hong-kong, disney, resorts

Hopefully i'll be going to Hong Kong in a couple of weeks and was planing to Hong Kong Disneyland Resort. When i went online to purchase the tickets i found out that there are 1-Day Tickets and 2-Day Tickets. I wanted to know how much do these tickets cover? Do they just grant entry or something else? I'm completely new to this so any help would do.

Answer (score 2):

The ticket (1 or 2 day) allows you the entrance and use of the park attractions nothing else, [is valid for 6 months since the first time you purchase it tho](https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/tickets/).

If you are looking for some discounts, special entraces and so, I recommend you to upgrade or buy the *[Magic Access](https://www.hongkongdisneyland.com/magic-access/)* that gives you special discounts and premium entrances to some events such as *Magic Access Summer Party*